# How can I remove image from datagridview image column from specific cell, actually I have to remove image from directory from specific folder

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I remove image from datagridview image column from specific cell, actually I have to remove image from directory from specific folder but it gives an error that image used by another process so please help me

```
filefullPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\PatientDocuments\\" + patId + "\\" + imge;

if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
{
   DialogResult mesg = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure Do You Want To Delete?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

   if (mesg == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
       BL_db.ImgId = imgeid;
       int i = Convert.ToInt32(dgvImage.SelectedRows[0].Index.ToString());

       dgvImage.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
       BL.Delete_PatientImage(BL_db);
       //DataGridViewImageColumn imgcolumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
       //imgcolumn.Dispose();

       //DataGridViewImageCell imgcell = new DataGridViewImageCell();
       // imgcell = (DataGridViewImageCell)dgvImage.Rows[dgvImage.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2];
       //imgcell.Dispose();

       //---------for delete file from directory-----------------------
       string[] arr1 = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "\\PatientDocuments\\" + patId, "*.jpg");

       foreach (string filePath in arr1)
       {
          if (filePath.Contains(".jpg"))
             File.Delete(filePath);
       }

       //-------------------------------------------------![enter image description here][1]`
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and saw a posting on Code Project:
[See Solution 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/576928/Cannotplusdeleteplusimagepluswhenplususedplusinplu)

It solved my problem.

**Edit:** Added important bits from link...

Basically, the Image.Load method causes the file to be locked for the duration of the program. It's hard to dispose of it.

Loading the image this way does not cause a locking problem.

```
// creating a bitmap from a stream
           using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(Filename, FileMode.Open))
           {
               Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fileStream);
               Image currentPicture = (Image)bitmap;
           }
```

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the solution in the answer itself.